# Discrete math - conjunction or disjunction in this case?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

> Teacher asks students if they did the homework on their own (everyone either did it on their own or copied it). He gets the following answers:
>
> 1. Andy: Everyone didn't do their homework on their own.
> 2. Barry: If Andy and Cindy did their homework then David copied it
> 3. Cindy: Andy did it on her own or Barry did it on his own
> 4. David: Barry did it on his own or Cindy did it on her own.
>
>    - Q1: Can everyone tell the truth?
>    - Q2: Can they all lie?
>    - Q3: The ones that did their homework on their own are talking the truth, the ones that copied it are lying. Who copied their homework?

The biggest question I have here is: **What do we say for Andy?  Do we use the disjunction or a conjunction?**

I did it this way $ \lnot A \lor \lnot B \lor \lnot C \lor \lnot D $  and I'm wondering if it's the right way or is the right way to use a conjunction?

Comment: I agree: "Everyone didn't" is ambiguous: it could suggest that all four did not, or that at least one did not.

Comment: Indeed. I used a disjunction and got the answer to Q1 that they can all tell the thurth. Q2: They can't all lie. And Q3: Barry copied his homework. If i use a conjunction though, I don't seem to get an answer to Q3, since there isn't a match in the table. In this case I assume the use of a disjunction is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "Everyone didn't do their homework on their own" is most likely intended to mean "All students didn't do their homework on their own." That is, the conjunction option: $$\neg A \land \neg B \land \neg C \land \neg D$$

For, if the disjunction was meant, we would have far more logical means to express this, e.g.:

- Someone didn't do their homework on their own
- Not everyone did their homework on their own

Answer (score 0):

Ffor Q3 you need to solve:

$ A \leftrightarrow ( \lnot A \lor  \lnot b \lor  \lnot C \lor  \lnot D ) $

$ B \leftrightarrow ( ( A \land C) \to  \lnot D ) $

$ C \leftrightarrow (  A \lor B ) $

$ D \leftrightarrow (  B \lor C ) $

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

**Some background**:

Andy's statement (*Everyone didn't do their homework on their own*) is better expressed using universal quantification, hence First Order Logic. Now, we know that the universal quantifier is equivalent to a conjunction of all elements of the universe:
$$ \forall x (\varphi) \equiv \bigwedge_{ a \in U} [\overline{a}/x]\varphi $$

**Your Answer**:

Since your universe is composed of 4 entities alone, namely, Andy, Barry, Cindy and David, it means that

$$ \forall x (\varphi) \equiv [\overline{a}/x]\varphi \wedge [\overline{b}/x]\varphi \wedge [\overline{c}/x]\varphi \wedge [\overline{c}/x]\varphi \wedge [\overline{d}/x]\varphi $$

Now, translating to your propositional glossary, this is the same as saying:

> $$¬A\wedge¬B\wedge¬C\wedge¬D$$